# Highcharts annotations not rendering

Tags: javascript, highcharts, annotations

I'm trying to dynamically add annotations to my high charts in React. I'm using the `addAnnotation` function to add a new annotation whenever a hover event is triggered on my app, but the annotation does not render. I dropped a debugger into my code, and when I call `chart.annotations` I can see there is currently an array of annotations, but they are not rendering. I even have make a call to the `addPlotLine` in this function and the plotline is rendered on the chart.  My config file looks like this

```
chart: {
      annotations: [{
        labelOptions: {
          backgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)',
          verticalAlign: 'top',
          align: 'right',
        }
      }],
      annotationsOptions: {
      },
    .... some lots more config options
}
```

and my on hover function to add the annotation is as follows

```
if( isNumber(value) )
   //this renders a plotline
    chart.xAxis[0].addPlotLine(baseChartHandle.generateInteractivePlotLine(value));
    // this doesn't render my annotation however
    chart.addAnnotation({
      linkedTo: value,
      title: {
        text: "It works!"
      }
    });
}
```

Comment: Did you include the annotations library (`modules/annotations.js`)?

Comment: I included `require('highcharts/modules/annotations')(ReactHighcharts.Highcharts);` in the file

Comment: Any other ideas? I have no idea why it is not working

Comment: I don't see any `linkedTo` or `title` properties for annotations in the **API**: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/annotations

I use `addAnnotation` method in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kkulig/owff40ch/ and it works fine when I provide the JSON structure specified in the API (point's `id` or coordinates(`x`, `y`, `xAxis`, `yAxis`)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that when I added annotations using Highcharts that the "linkedTo" function never worked despite my trials.

Despite adding a guid to my point, it never was able to apply it. I would suggest in your case adding it by x and y value, then finding the point that way instead. Here is how I have added annotations in the past successfully:

```
 series.data.forEach(function (point) {

                var annotationObject =
                    {
                        id: point.id,
                        labelOptions: {
                            y: 15,
                            verticalAlign: 'bottom',
                            distance: 25
                        },
                        labels: []
                    };

                }

                var text = <get text you want to push>;

                annotationObject.labels.push(
                    {
                        point: {
                            xAxis: 0,
                            yAxis: 0,
                            x: point.x,
                            y: point.y
                        },
                        text: text
                    }

                );

                _chart.addAnnotation(annotationObject);
            });
```

I also found a bug in HighCharts when using remove annotations, as a heads up. Each point will need an id like above, but it should be called by this line:

```
           _chart.removeAnnotation(id);
```

It will remove the annotation, however you will get *lots* of complaints from highcharts if you try to do anything after, and it will break. I found the answer here, in annotations.js :

[image]

The red box is code I added. If you do removeAnnotation(ann.id), and it rerenders, it will fail because the labels object is null. Adding this check lets you do that without the labelCollectors failing.

Happy charting.

Comment: Thanks for the response, however, it doesn't seem to work. I get the same result as before. It pushes the annotation object into the charts annotation array but nothing is rendered.

Comment: The points on my chart have no y value only an x value if that makes any difference.

Comment: I don't understand why but I had to change both `xAxis` and `yAxis` to an integer other than 0 for it to render anything. There isn't any documentation on these two keys on the highcharts section for labels so I'm not sure what is going on. https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/annotations.labels

Comment: The x and y axis integers are telling the chart what index in the array of xaxis items to put this on. You may have more than one axis being setup and not realize it.